# Neldermead function from nloptr package - negative parameters limitation

Tags: r, calibration

Is there a way to prevent neldermead() from returning negative parameter values? Negative values provide nonsensical results for the model I wish to calibrate using a neldermead() function

Comment: Either return an objective value worse than any other value if any parameters are negative or else replace each parameter p with abs(p) in the objective function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.